# Babel transpiled code does not support static methods in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Babel transpiled js works fine, but on IE11 the static inheritance seems not to work. Any idea?

```
class SuperClass {
    constructor () {}

    static test () {}
}

class Sub extends SuperClass {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }
}

Sub.test(); //Results in: "Object doesn't support property or method 'test'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Babel does not handle the case, in fact in the `inherits` helper, if the `Object.setPrototypeOf` method is `undefined`, Babel simply attaches the super class to the `__proto__` key.

I have managed this issue including this [polyfill/workaround](https://gist.github.com/edoardocavazza/47246856759f2273e48b) at the. At the moment, it seems to work fine, until the Babel team won't fix this behavior.

Comment: The funny thing is that setPrototypeOf is an es2015 feature :).

Comment: This solved my similar issue with a React app in IE10. Thanks!