# Access static method from es6 class/webcomponents compiled with babel in IE 11

Tags: javascript, frameworks, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I'm develepping a custom js framework using es6 class and webcomponents.
I'm trying to support IE11 by compiling my code with babel to es2015 and adding the webcomponents library.

```
class baseControl extends HTMLElement{
    static element(nodeName){
        // 'this' is the current class object
        return document.registerElement(nodeName, this);
    }
}
```

And there, a little exemple of my problem :

```
class SubControl extends baseControl{
     static secondStaticMethod(){
          // some stuff
     }

}

SubControl
    .element("sub-control")
    .secondStaticMethod() //Object doesn't support property or method 'secondStaticMethod'
```

With IE11, the "element" call works well, but the "secondStaticMethod" function is not recognized.
My guess is that the "registerElement" function doesn't copy the statics methods of my class

Is there a way to bypass this problem ?

Comment: Perhaps similiar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183086/babel-transpiled-code-does-not-support-static-methods-in-ie11

Comment: I edited my example to be easier to understand. The problem described in your post is slightly different from mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.registerElement is deprecated.

See [customElements.define](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements)